# Strange recycling of factors in dplyr::mutate - bug or feature?

Tags: r, dplyr

The function `mutate` from the R package 'dplyr' has a peculiar recycling feature for factors, in that it seems to return the factor `as.numeric`. In the following example `y` becomes what you would expect, whereas `z` is `c(1,1)`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(x=1:2)
glimpse(df %>% mutate(y="A", z=factor("B")))
# Variables:
# $ x (int) 1, 2
# $ y (chr) "A", "A"
# $ z (int) 1, 1
```

Is there any rationale behind this, or is it a bug?

(I am using R 3.1.1 and dplyr 0.3.0.1.)

---

EDIT:

After posting this as an issue on github, Romain Francois fixed it within hours! So if the above is a problem use `devtools::install_github` to get the latest version:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("hadley/dplyr")
```

and then

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(x=1:2)
glimpse(df %>% mutate(y="A", z=factor("B")))
# Variables:
# $ x (int) 1, 2
# $ y (chr) "A", "A"
# $ z (fctr) B, B
```

Nice work Romain!

Comment: This behavior seems to be due to vector recycling. If you specify a factor of length 2, e.g., `glimpse(df %>% mutate(y="A", z=factor(c("B", "C"))))`,  the variable `z` will be of factor class.

Comment: One way to get a factor variable would be `df %>% do(data.frame(., y="A", z= factor("B"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))`

Comment: @akrun Why is `mutate` not the right choice? Any guess?

Comment: @jazzurro I don't know the right answer here.  It could be a bug or a feature.  I expected it to work with factor of length 1. Perhaps, by recyling, it gets converted to `numeric`.  So, one possibility will be to use `rep`.  `df %>% mutate(y="A", z= factor(rep("B",2)))`

Comment: Thanks for comments. There is certainly no problem finding a way to get what I want in this situation, I was just puzzled by `mutate`'s behaviour. It seems wrong to me. Since `rep` has been discussed, I'll add: you might want to use this simultaneous with, say, `filter` in which case you might not know how many times you should repeat the factor (and in such a case recycling would be very useful).

Comment: @Henrik Renlund I would replace `2` with `n()` if that is what you mentioned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

dplyr uses C++ to perform the actual `mutate` operation. [Following](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/9dd3ec70322cf214c20791736019839909f8483d/R/tbl-data-frame.R#L44) [the](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/b29c43592bb44ed1a94a8c9d68825f995f20d39a/R/manip-df.r#L20) [rabbit](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/b29c43592bb44ed1a94a8c9d68825f995f20d39a/R/manip-df.r#L22) [hole](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/937dda97940cc71258c38a5b2f1a03c8d0d73199/src/dplyr.cpp#L1967) and noting this is an [ungrouped mutation](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/937dda97940cc71258c38a5b2f1a03c8d0d73199/src/dplyr.cpp#L1875), we can use our trusty debugger to notice the following.

```
debugonce(dplyr:::mutate_impl)
# Inside of mutate_impl we do:
class(dots[[2]]$expr) # which is a "call"!
```

So now we know the type of our [lazy expression](https://github.com/hadley/lazyeval). We [eval](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/937dda97940cc71258c38a5b2f1a03c8d0d73199/src/dplyr.cpp#L1904) the call and [notice](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/937dda97940cc71258c38a5b2f1a03c8d0d73199/src/dplyr.cpp#L1920) it is a [supported type](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/9dd3ec70322cf214c20791736019839909f8483d/inst/include/dplyr/check_supported_type.h#L8) (unfortunately, R's `TYPEOF` macro claims [factors are integers](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-wrap-and-recurse/) - we would need `Rf_isFactor` to discriminate).

So what happens next? We [returned the result](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/937dda97940cc71258c38a5b2f1a03c8d0d73199/src/dplyr.cpp#L1946) and we're done. If you have tried `(df %>% mutate(y="A", z=factor(c("A","B"))))[[3]]` already, you'll know that the issue is indeed the recycling.

[Specifically](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/937dda97940cc71258c38a5b2f1a03c8d0d73199/src/dplyr.cpp#L1929),  the C++ [Gatherer object](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/da44c79aa814b2bfae6f3b9fc4673789a5cc2269/inst/include/dplyr/Gatherer.h) (which [should really](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/da44c79aa814b2bfae6f3b9fc4673789a5cc2269/inst/include/dplyr/Gatherer.h#L187) be checking for `Rf_isFactor` in addition to its current date check on `INTSXP`s) is using C++ templating to [force a `Vector<INTSXP>`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/da44c79aa814b2bfae6f3b9fc4673789a5cc2269/inst/include/dplyr/Gatherer.h#L133)  to be created (implicitly through constructor initialization - notice the arity 2 call in `ConstantGathererImpl`) without remembering to carry over the factor "label."

TLDR: In R's C++, integers and factors have the same internal type when using the `TYPEOF` macro, and factors are a weird edge case.

Feel free to submit a pull request to dplyr, it's in active development and hadley and Romain are nice guys. You'll have to add an if statement [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/da44c79aa814b2bfae6f3b9fc4673789a5cc2269/inst/include/dplyr/Gatherer.h#L187).

Comment: Thanks @Robert Krzyzanowski. I don't dare start messing with the C++ code, but I did add this as an issue on github: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/715